# Multithread blocking in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, wait, notify

I have class Client and method called listRooms().

```
public synchronized RoomInfo[] listRooms() {
    sendMessage(new Message("@refresh"));

    try {
        System.out.println("#1");
        wait();
        System.out.println("#2");
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }

    if( m_RoomListMessage == null )
        return null;

    RoomInfo[] rooms = new RoomInfo[ m_RoomListMessage.getInteger(0) ];
    for(int i=0; i<rooms.length; i++) {
        rooms[i] = new RoomInfo( 
                m_RoomListMessage.getString(3*i + 1),
                m_RoomListMessage.getBoolean(3*i + 2),
                m_RoomListMessage.getInteger(3*i+3)
        );
    }

    return rooms;

}
```

I also have class Listener (extends Thread) which listens for incoming messages from server. As the message arrives listener thread reads Message (using ObjectInputStream) and then calls next method.

```
public synchronized void processMessage(Message aMessage) {     
    if( aMessage.type.equals("@roomlist") ) {
        m_RoomListMessage = aMessage;
        notify();
        System.out.println("notificiran xD");
        return;
    }

    MessageHandler handler = m_MessageHandlers.get(aMessage.type);
    if( handler == null ) {
        System.out.println("No MessageHandler for: " + aMessage.type);
        return;
    }

    handler.onMessage(aMessage);
}
```

The problem is it waits forever. processMessage() is never called after I sent @refresh message and my server shows that it sent message containing list of all rooms on server, also method is called from Listener thread but listRooms() is called from object LobbyView (extends View which extends JPanel) attached to object of ClientWindow (extends JFrame), so it is different thread. And I don't know why is it blocked. So Listener obviously cannot call processMessage but I don't know why or I have some wrong understanding of threads in Java :D

EDIT: It also indicates that Listener thread is blocked for some reason...

Comment: Please create and include [a minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your problem that allows it to be reproduced.

Comment: What are you `synchronized` on and who are you `wait` and `notify`ing? It looks very much like to completely different classes.

Answer (score 3):

> The problem is it waits forever. processMessage() is never called after I sent @refresh message

Looks to me that your `listRooms()` call is doing a `wait` on the `Client` object while your `processMessage(...)` method is calling `notify()` on a `Listener` object.  For the `notify()` to wake up the other thread it must be on the same object instance.  When you have a `synchronized` method, it is locking on the `this` object instance.

These two objects must share a common lock object to be able to signal each other.  One way you can do this is to pass in a lock object into both the `Client` and the `Listener` and then do something like:

```
 synchronized (commonLock) {
     commonLock.wait();
 }
```

...

```
 synchronized (commonLock) {
     commonLock.notify();
 }
```

> EDIT: It also indicates that Listener thread is blocked for some reason...

I don't know why the `Listener` would be blocked but it's not because of the `notify()` call.

Comment: Or maybe even use a [`Lock`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html). P.S. right as always, +1

Comment: I know it is not blocked because of that but it is, since when I send message refresh, server responds with message roomlist, and I put some code for printing messages on arrival, and it does print all messages that arrived before sending @refresh and after that roomlist message is never printed so ObjectInputStream never read object, so Listener Thread must be blockes for unknown reason

Comment: @Gray
I created class CommonLock and field lock in Client class. Then I put this code
    synchronized(CommonLock.class) { lock.wait }
in roomList()

and 
   synchronized(CommonLock.class) { lock.notify() }
int processMessage method.
and I get IllegalMonitorStateException

Comment: You need to synchronize on the `lock` not its class object.  I think you need to read a tutorial on locking: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sync.html